# sql case in where clause to select item

Tags: sql

I have the following statement

```
    SELECT b.Prig
    FROM Tirr tr
    JOIN Bud b 
    ON tr.ID = b.ID
    WHERE b.Syst = 1 and tr.Salesmen = @SalesID
```

In the above statement, I need to do b.Syst = 1 only if b.Call is not  '55' so I need a case statement but not sure how to incorporate it

I have tried:

```
    SELECT b.Prig
    FROM Tirr tr
    JOIN Bud b 
    ON tr.ID = b.ID
    WHERE 
    case b.Call
    when '55' then 
      b.Syst = 1 and tr.Salesmen = @SalesID
    else 
     tr.Salesmen = @SalesID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    b.Prig
FROM Tirr tr
JOIN Bud b 
    ON tr.ID = b.ID
WHERE tr.Salesmen = @SalesID
AND ((b.Call = '55' AND b.syst = 1) OR b.Call <> '55')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to you could still use case

```
SELECT b.prig 
FROM   tirr tr 
       JOIN bud b 
         ON tr.id = b.id 
WHERE  CASE b.call 
         WHEN '55' THEN b.syst 
         ELSE 1 
       END = 1 
       AND tr.salesmen = @SalesID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.Prig
FROM Tirr tr
JOIN Bud b 
ON tr.ID = b.ID
WHERE 
    (isnull(b.Call,'') != '55' and b.Syst = 1) or b.Call = '55') 
    and tr.Salesmen = @SalesID
```

Comment: Not sure if this will because of the or condition. If it is not 55 then definitely need to do b.Syst = 1 and b.Call = '55'

Comment: Sorry, i was looking at your case statement to see what your goal was. Edited this to reflect " I need to do b.Syst = 1 only if b.Call is not '55' "